# Access a user's files from another account

Tags: dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I want to integrate Dropbox to my web app. The idea is that, having a user's mail and password I can access his files and allow him to work with them, all this using APIs. Is this possible, can anyone point me out to an example or explain how can I achieve this, I'm new to Dropbox APIs so if this is to simple to answer please do it anyway. I'm using php.

Comment: You will need to allow the user to authorize your app with DropBox: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#authorize and then you will need to access the "GET" and "PUT" functions of the API which are documented here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET and here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put

Comment: Any code you've tried before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in APAD1's comment this can't be done with out the express user authorization. the oauth will redirect the user to a page and there he will aprove your request to use his data through APIs.